# WMS GetFeatureInfo on a popup-Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have the below code. When I launch this in Chrome,  the map with the overlay displays fine and there is no error message in the console. However, there is no response when clicking on the map. I have downloaded L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js.

My issue is nearly similar if not similar to the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813632/how-to-get-attribute-info-of-wms-layer-published-in-geoserver-in-a-popup-via-le

However when I tried suggested solution

```
var nexrad = L.tileLayer.betterWMS("https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi", {
    layers: 'nexrad-n0r',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: "Weather data &copy; 2015 IEM Nexrad"
  });
```

I get an error message that:

`Uncaught TypeError: L.tileLayer.betterWMS is not a function
at addLayersLeaflet.html:129`

Any guidance to point me to where my problem is?

Here is the code that display with no GetFeatureInfo response:

```
</script>
//Base Layers
      var OSM = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        maxZoom: 18
      });

    //July 2019 - The following MapQuest URL is no longer supported as HTTPS endpoint and has been replaced with the ESRI WorldImagery tile layer.

    /*
             var MapQuestOpen_Aerial = L.tileLayer('http://oatile{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {               /*
            var MapQuestOpen_Aerial = L.tileLayer('h', {
                 attribution: 'Tiles Courtesy of <a href="http://www.mapquest.com/">MapQuest</a> &mdash; Portions Courtesy NASA/JPL-Caltech and U.S. Depart. of Agriculture, Farm Service Agency',                   attribution: 'Tiles Courtesy of <a href="http://www.mapquest.com/">MapQuest</a> &mdash; Portions Courtesy NASA/JPL-Caltech and U.S. Depart. of Agriculture, Farm Service Agency',
                 subdomains: '1234'                  subdomains: '1234'
             });                 });
            */

            var Esri_WorldImagery = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
        attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
     });

          var nexrad = var nexrad = L.tileLayer.betterWms("https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi", {
            layers: 'nexrad-n0r',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true,
            attribution: "Weather data &copy; 2015 IEM Nexrad"
          });

          //create the map
          var map = L.map('map', {
            center: new L.LatLng(44, -91),
            zoom: 5,
            layers: [OSM, nexrad]
          });
          //layer control
          var baseMaps = {
            "OpenStreetMap": OSM,
            "ESRI  World Imnagery": Esri_WorldImagery
          };
          var overlayMaps = {
            "Radar": nexrad
          };
          L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);

        </script>
```

L.TileLayer.BetterWMS js:

```
L.TileLayer.BetterWMS = L.TileLayer.WMS.extend({

  onAdd: function (mapid) {
    // Triggered when the layer is added to a map.
    //   Register a click listener, then do all the upstream WMS things
    L.TileLayer.WMS.prototype.onAdd.call(this, mapid);
    map.on('click', this.getFeatureInfo, this);
  },

  onRemove: function (mapid) {
    // Triggered when the layer is removed from a map.
    //   Unregister a click listener, then do all the upstream WMS things
    L.TileLayer.WMS.prototype.onRemove.call(this, mapid);
    map.off('click', this.getFeatureInfo, this);
  },

  getFeatureInfo: function (evt) {
    // Make an AJAX request to the server and hope for the best
    var url = this.getFeatureInfoUrl(evt.latlng),
        showResults = L.Util.bind(this.showGetFeatureInfo, this);
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        var err = typeof data === 'string' ? null : data;
        showResults(err, evt.latlng, data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        showResults(error);  
      }
    });
  },

  getFeatureInfoUrl: function (latlng) {
    // Construct a GetFeatureInfo request URL given a point
    var point = this._map.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng, this._map.getZoom()),
        size = this._map.getSize(),

        params = {
          request: 'GetFeatureInfo',
          service: 'WMS',
          srs: 'EPSG:4326',
          styles: this.wmsParams.styles,
          transparent: this.wmsParams.transparent,
          version: this.wmsParams.version,      
          format: this.wmsParams.format,
          bbox: this._map.getBounds().toBBoxString(),
          height: size.y,
          width: size.x,
          layers: this.wmsParams.layers,
          query_layers: this.wmsParams.layers,
          info_format: 'text/html'
        };

    params[params.version === '1.3.0' ? 'i' : 'x'] = point.x;
    params[params.version === '1.3.0' ? 'j' : 'y'] = point.y;

    return this._url + L.Util.getParamString(params, this._url, true);
  },

  showGetFeatureInfo: function (err, latlng, content) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); return; } // do nothing if there's an error

    // Otherwise show the content in a popup, or something.
    L.popup({ maxWidth: 800})
      .setLatLng(latlng)
      .setContent(content)
      .openOn(this._map);
  }
});

L.tileLayer.betterWms = function (url, options) {
  return new L.TileLayer.BetterWMS(url, options);  
};
```

Comment: you seem to have way more code than would be required to show the issue

Comment: I see the code I have put there is actually the same thing in the L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js.  I will edit the code.

Comment: I currently get this error <?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/exception_1_1_1.dtd">
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
<ServiceException code="LayerNotDefined">
msWMSFeatureInfo(): WMS server error. Layer(s) specified in QUERY_LAYERS parameter is not offered by the service instance.
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. Thank you @ nmtoken. This helped me https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938 . Basically after cleaning the code I did this; var nexrad = L.tileLayer.betterWms and it is returning a WMS getfeatureinfo url.

Answer (score 2):

There might be nothing wrong with your code.

One issue if you are trying to query the `nexrad-n0r` layer (actually any layer) in the `IEM WMS Service`

> https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

is that (as can be seen in the GetCapabilities response above) none of the layers is queryable; so you will not be able to do a GetFeatureInfo request.

[image: GetCapabilities response]

Comment: You are absolutely right, the layer I was using to test was un queryable. My own WMS worked just perfectly.